# How to convert bytearray to image in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, arrays

This is the Case
i have an unsigned char pointer to BMP image data
after i loop with the pointer i achieved a byte array contain int values 0 - 255

What i want is convert this values in the array to  BMP image
to display it in UIImage.

**the image is in gray scale

Comment: So it's a memory image of a BMP-format file, or do you just mean 'BMP' more generically so that you have, e.g. 100 bytes to represent a 10x10 greyscale image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet is from this [blog](http://paulsolt.com/2010/09/ios-converting-uiimage-to-rgba8-bitmaps-and-back/), I recommend you take a look there and the [project site in Github](https://gist.github.com/739132)

Also Note that this class method works for RGB8 Images, so you will need to make changes in 
`bitsPerPixel` (it should be 8 for grayscale), `bytesPerRow` (1 * width), `bufferLength` (remove * 4) and create `colorSpaceRef` using `CGColorCreateGenericGray` instead.

Also I've noticed that creating the color space with `CGColorCreateGenericGray` assumes that your array has alpha info. So maybe you should add an alpha byte for each pixel to make it work properly.

```
+ (UIImage *) convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:(unsigned char *) buffer 
            withWidth:(int) width
           withHeight:(int) height {


    size_t bufferLength = width * height * 4;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, bufferLength, NULL);
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
    size_t bytesPerRow = 4 * width;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if(colorSpaceRef == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error allocating color space");
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        return nil;
    }

    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, 
                height, 
                bitsPerComponent, 
                bitsPerPixel, 
                bytesPerRow, 
                colorSpaceRef, 
                bitmapInfo, 
                provider,   // data provider
                NULL,       // decode
                YES,            // should interpolate
                renderingIntent);

    uint32_t* pixels = (uint32_t*)malloc(bufferLength);

    if(pixels == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Memory not allocated for bitmap");
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
        CGImageRelease(iref);       
        return nil;
    }

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, 
                 width, 
                 height, 
                 bitsPerComponent, 
                 bytesPerRow, 
                 colorSpaceRef, 
                 bitmapInfo); 

    if(context == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error context not created");
        free(pixels);
    }

    UIImage *image = nil;
    if(context) {

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), iref);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

        // Support both iPad 3.2 and iPhone 4 Retina displays with the correct scale
        if([UIImage respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:)]) {
            float scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        } else {
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        }

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);   
        CGContextRelease(context);  
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(iref);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    if(pixels) {
        free(pixels);
    }   
    return image;
}
```

Comment: 2011-10-05 04:26:04.273 Sample[1481:6603] BMP
Oct  5 04:26:04 macs-iPad Sample[1481] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 24 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaNone; 350 bytes/row.
Oct  5 04:26:04 macs-iPad Sample[1481] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0

Comment: thx a lot your answer was very good, but there is one thing the image appear shifted i don't know why

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine something like this. Untested, so be ready to tweak :)

```
UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithBytes: yourCharPointer length : sizeof(yourCharPointer)]];
```

Comment: Firstly, based on the question, it sounds like the image data is just an array of pixel values so imageWithData wouldn't know what to do with it. A BMP file header would have to be prepended to the image data. Secondly, sizeof(yourCharPointer) would yield 4 or 8 depending on the CPU.

Comment: by the way @Patrick Perini your code doesn't need testing it is worked as it is ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the accepted answer is to long, I've wrote another solution:

```
- (UIImage*) imageFromArray:(const char*)pixelArray width:(int)width height:(int)height {

    int imageSizeInPixels = width * height;
    int bytesPerPixel = 2; // 1 byte for brightness, 1 byte for alpha
    unsigned char *pixels = (unsigned char *)malloc(imageSizeInPixels * bytesPerPixel);
    memset(pixels, 255, imageSizeInPixels * bytesPerPixel); // setting alpha values to 255
    for (int i = 0; i < imageSizeInPixels; i++) {
        pixels[i * 2] = pixelArray[i]; // writing array of bytes as image brightnesses
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, pixels, imageSizeInPixels * bytesPerPixel, NULL);
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 8 * bytesPerPixel, width * bytesPerPixel, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big, provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    return image;
}
```